# Pass list to function by value

Tags: python, pass-by-value

I want to pass a list into function by value.
By default, lists and other complex objects passed to function by reference.
Here is some desision:

```
def add_at_rank(ad, rank):
    result_ = copy.copy(ad)
    .. do something with result_
    return result_
```

Can this be written shorter?
In other words, I wanna not to change **ad**.

Comment: if `ad` is a list, you can do `result_ = ad[:]`

Comment: It can't really be written shorter, no.  You have to explicitly copy the list.  You can either do that outside the function or inside the function, but you have to do it.

Comment: Actually the _reference_ is passed by value

Comment: The terms "by value" and "by reference" aren't used often in Python, because they tend to be misleading to people coming from other languages. As @gnibbler says, everything is passed by value in Python—but some values are references. :)

Comment: Also, the usual Pythonic way to deal with this is to avoid mutating `result_` in the first place; create a new `list` by transforming the old one (e.g., with a list comprehension, `map`, `filter`, etc.). Sometimes that's not appropriate, and without knowing what your ".. do something with result_" code looks like or does, it's impossible to say whether that's true here. But it's appropriate far more often than newcomers to Python (especially from languages like Java or C++) expect.

Comment: abarnet, you right, I come from another world :) - the world of compilation-language.

Comment: What you call variables are actually [names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) in Python. They are *references* to objects, not the objects themselves. Read the linked article for a better understanding of names and values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `[:]`, but for list containing lists(or other mutable objects) you should go for `copy.deepcopy()`:

`lis[:]` is equivalent to `list(lis)` or `copy.copy(lis)`, and returns a shallow copy of the list.

```
In [33]: def func(lis):
    print id(lis)
   ....:     

In [34]: lis = [1,2,3]

In [35]: id(lis)
Out[35]: 158354604

In [36]: func(lis[:])
158065836
```

When to use `deepcopy()`:

```
In [41]: lis = [range(3), list('abc')]

In [42]: id(lis)
Out[42]: 158066124

In [44]: lis1=lis[:]

In [45]: id(lis1)
Out[45]: 158499244  # different than lis, but the inner lists are still same

In [46]: [id(x) for x in lis1] = =[id(y) for y in lis]
Out[46]: True

In [47]: lis2 = copy.deepcopy(lis)  

In [48]: [id(x) for x in lis2] == [id(y) for y in lis]  
Out[48]: False
```

Answer (score 7):

This might be an interesting use case for a decorator function. Something like this:

```
def pass_by_value(f):
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        args_copied = copy.deepcopy(args)
        kwargs_copied = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
        return f(*args_copied, **kwargs_copied)
    return _f
```

`pass_by_value` takes a function `f` as input and creates a new function `_f` that deep-copies all its parameters and then passes them to the original function `f`.

Usage:

```
@pass_by_value
def add_at_rank(ad, rank):
    ad.append(4)
    rank[3] = "bar"
    print "inside function", ad, rank

a, r = [1,2,3], {1: "foo"}
add_at_rank(a, r)
print "outside function", a, r
```

Output:

```
"inside function [1, 2, 3, 4] {1: 'foo', 3: 'bar'}"
"outside function [1, 2, 3] {1: 'foo'}"
```

Comment: nice one. also, it's best to decorate your inner `_f` with `@functools.wraps(f)`

Answer (score 0):

A shallow copy is usually good enough, and potentially mush faster than deep copy.

You can take advantage of this if the modifications you are making to `result_` are not mutating the items/attributes it *contains*.

For a simple example if you have a chessboard

```
board = [[' ']*8 for x in range(8)]
```

You could make a shallow copy

```
board2 = copy.copy(board)
```

It's safe to append/insert/pop/delete/replace items from `board2`, but not the lists it contains. If you want to modify one of the contianed lists you must create a new list and `replace` the existing one

```
row = list(board2[2])
row[3] = 'K'
board2[2] = row
```

It's a little more work, but a lot more efficient in time and storage

Answer (score 0):

In case of *ad* is *list* you can simple call your function as `add_at_rank(ad + [], rank)`.

This will create NEW instance of *list* every time you call function, that value equivalented of *ad*.

```
>>>ad == ad + []
True

>>>ad is ad +[]
False
```

Pure pythonic :)