# function storing value of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code as below:

```
def f(x,l=[]):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l) 

f(2)
f(3)
```

Why it gives as:

```
 [0, 1]
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

for f(3) ? why it is storing value of l ? Isn't it supposed to be local temporary variable ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Please check your indentation, the code you posted will not work.

Comment: A simpler explanation can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377050/pass-list-to-function-by-value) rather than the one posted.

Comment: TL; DR default args are evaluated when the function is _defined_. They are _not_ evaluated each time the function is called.

Comment: Even its a duplicate, a workaround is  `'def f(x,l=None):\n    if l is None :\n        l=[]\n    for i in range(x):\n        l.append(i*i)\n    print(l)\n'`

Comment: @B.M. That works, but there's no need here for `l` to be an arg at all, it can just be a normal local variable.

Comment: @PM 2Ring : I think OP wants in some case add some numbers in the output .

Comment: Why it is different from:
`code def foo(i, x=[]):
        x.append(i*i) 
    return x
for i in range(3):
    y = foo(i)
    print(y)`

'